# finding inverse map

Tags: differential-geometry

Could someone help me find the inverse of $\psi(u,v)= (\frac{2u}{u^2+v^2+1},\frac{2v}{u^2+v^2+1},\frac{u^2+v^2-1}{u^2+v^2+1})$ I tried $u=x,\frac{2u}{u^2+v^2+1}=x $ ect, but I can't find it. any hints?

Comment: Try u = x/(1 - z) and v = u y/x.

Comment: Thank you. How did you come up with that ?

Comment: If your triple is denoted $(x,y,z)$ then some algebra shows $x^2+y^2+z^2=1.$ I think the map is stereographic projection from $(u,v)$ plane to unit sphere, may have a point like north pole on the sphere not in image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid coordinates whenever possible.  Regard $\psi$ as a map from $\mathbb R^3$ to itself identifying $(u,v)$ with $(u,v,0)$.  Define $n=(0,0,1)$ and $q=(u,v,0)$.  We have
$$\psi(q)=\frac{1}{\|q\|^2+1}\bigr(2q+n(\|q\|^2-1)\bigr).$$
Geometrically, $\psi(q)$ is the intersection of a point $q$, which is perpendicular to $n$ and the point $n$ on the unit sphere.

Now the inverse mapping maps a point $p$ on the unit share -- different from $n$ -- to the plane orthogonal to $n$. To determine $\psi^{-1}(p)$ calculate the point on the straight line through $n$ and $p$,
$$n+t(p-n),$$
which is orthogonal to $n$, that is
$$\langle n+t(p-n),n\rangle=0\iff t=\frac{1}{1-\langle n,p\rangle}.$$
Finally,
$$\psi^{-1}(p)=\frac{p-\langle n,p\rangle n}{1-\langle n,p\rangle}.$$
You may feel free to write the equation with coordinates ...